Duplicates in outlook GAL (python)
Would anyone be able to help me with this issue? I'm making a App that looks in a GAL (global address list) in outlook and finds the EX-user and stuff, I have that working and all but when I am getting the contacts/address entries from doing this:
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
address_list = namespace.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
gal = address_list.AddressEntries

there are people who have the same Name and same display name as others, while being unique. when I need the EX-user I do
gal.item("LastName, FirstName").GetExchangeUser(),

but as there are some duplicates In gal with the same name it always returns first one.
was wondering if any really smart person would know how I could detect duplicates, remove duplicates and what not. I have a list of names to look at thought the gal and what I thought i could do is find the contact by doing gal.item("LastName, FirstName") and getting the position of it and then moving to the next item until there is a diffrent name. But idk how to get the position when i do .item("name").
Any help appreciated, Marcus.  Note: I would like to avoid loop though gal as theres alot of people in there.

If you know the name, the standard way to get address entry details is to call Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve. If the name is ambiguous however, Recipient.Resolve will return false. Other than looping through all entries, there isn't much you can do using Outlook Object Model alone - there is no way to get the list of ambiguous entries similar to the list shown by the "Duplicate Names" dialog in Outlook unless you use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (I am its author - any language). If using Redemption is an option, it exposes RDOAddressBook.ResolveNameEx and RDOAddressList.ResolveNameEx methods, which return a list of matches either against the whole address book (RDOSession.AddressBook.ResolveNameEx) or just the GAL container (RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx).
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
session = outlook.Session

# Initialize Redemption Session
redemption_session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")
redemption_session.MAPIOBJECT = session.MAPIOBJECT

# Resolve the name in the Global Address List
search_name = "LastName, FirstName"  
addr_entries = redemption_session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx(search_name)
       
# Iterate through each resolved address entry and display the name
for ae in addr_entries:
       show_message_box(ae.Name, "Resolved Name")


Thanks alot Dmitry. I have decided to make it with C++!
